# Inequality for all integers greater than 2 .

Tags: inequality

Fr all integers $n\geq 2$ , define $f_{n} (x) $ = $(x+1)^{1/n} - x^{1/n}$, where $x>0$ . Then as a function of x

a.) $f_{n} (x) $ is increasing for all n

b.)$f_{n} (x) $ is a decreasing function of n

c.) $f_{n} (x) $ is increasing for odd n and decreasing for even n.

d.)$f_{n} (x) $ is decreasing for odd n and increasing for even n.

My attempt : I could apply some intuition and then check for n = 2 and specific values of x to get the correct answer by observing a pattern . 
However I am looking for a more formal way to solve the question.

Comment: is the use of differentiation permitted?

Comment: You attempt is not really inspiring. If you've got this as an assignment, you should know the ways to solve it

Comment: To distinguish these choices, all you need is to check when $x \to 0,1$.

Comment: Thanks got it Macavity , if you would post this as an answer I could close the question !